# Does a duplicate entries in a PATH variable revoke the precedence given by the first entry?

Tags: path

If I have a PATH variable that (when exploded onto multiple lines) contains something like this (with a few notes added by me):

```
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin
/Users/brandon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin   # <<--- notice this path appears again later
/usr/bin         # <<--- notice this comes AFTER /usr/local/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin   # <<--- here it is again!
/usr/local/git/bin
/Users/brandon/bin
/Users/brandon/.homebrew/bin
/usr/local/mysql/bin
/usr/local/share/npm/bin
/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin
/Users/brandon/.rvm/bin
```

is it possible for the presence of the second `/usr/local/bin/` to cause the `/usr/bin` to take precedence over `/usr/local/bin`?  This seems crazy (to me: I've never heard of such a thing) but that's exactly the behavior I'm seeing.  I've just installed PHP with Homebrew, and yet the system PHP (from `/usr/bin`) is taking precedence:

```
$ which php
/usr/bin/php
```

***BUT***, after manually altering the PATH (rather than digging through all the files sourced by my `.zshrc` to try to figure out why & where the duplication is coming from) to remove the ***second*** instance of `/usr/local/bin`, I find that `/usr/local/bin` is taking precedence over `/usr/bin` as I would have expected it to in the first place:

```
$ which php
/usr/local/bin/php
```

What would cause this?  Is this normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hash -r` (for `bash`) If you just installed a binary, the shell may not know about it immediately as it does maintain a cache (vs. scanning `PATH` for *every* command.)

The path is scanned in order, duplicates make absolutely no difference. However, dumber shells may scan the duplicate entry more than once -- if foo is there twice and bar isn't in foo, foo may get scanned twice.

Comment: aha! Yes I should have thought of that.  The fact that things changed after manually altering my PATH was just coincidence of timing.  Makes perfect sense now.