# Debian terminal looks for a binary in wrong directory

Tags: debian, directory

I installed the Smalltalk language from source. The binary was placed in /usr/local/bin/. For some reasons i uninstalled it and installed the version existing in the synaptic package manager which places the binary in /usr/bin/. Now running gst (GNU Smalltalk) in the terminal will search for the binary in /usr/local/bin/, as this path has been set during the `./configure` of my source-installation. How can i instruct it to look into the correct path (/usr/bin)?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: /home/amir/bin:/home/amir/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

Comment: Are you using bash? If so, what is the output of `grep 'PATH=' ~/.bashrc`? (Please tag me with `@Sparhawk` so I am notified of any replies.) Also, does the binary in `/usr/local/bin/` still exist?

Comment: I would also look for a softlink (`ls -s`) using `which smalltalk` (or whatever it is you use to run the program) that points to your old location `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: I would just create a symbolic link.

Comment: If the question weren't misattributing this to the "terminal", which has nothing whatever to do with it, perhaps there would be answers.  Perhaps people would remember that this is a shell feature.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115992/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47363/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150922/